# how to define a class in only one line?

Tags: ruby, class

I tried

```
class X begin end
```

and

```
class X {}
```

neight correct. What is the right code?

Comment: Most of the time, newline is the statement delimiter. If you want multiple statements on the same line, you need to use ; which is also supported.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need a semicolon after `class X`:

```
class X; end
```

Answer (score 27):

correct and verified example:

```
class C; end
```

and another, tricky solution :)

```
C = Class.new
```

Comment: You forgot that `Class.new` accepts an argument which is the class to inherit from. This is especially nice for defining exception classes... `MyCustomNotImplementedError = Class.new(NotImplementedError)`